# VsCode SCSS Can't compile (setting)

Tags: visual-studio-code, sass

My vscode scss tool cannot compile
I can't find the reason
Attach pictures[enter image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KePtD.png)description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfm7Q.png)

I tried compiling this archive to another computer and the result was normal. I suspect there is something wrong with my scss settings, but I don't know where the problem is.